# Yii2 translation i18n with multiple files

Tags: php, yii2, internationalization, translation

i have a question about i18n with yii2. As i have a pretty big app, i did several files under /backend/messages/en-US like this app.php explication.php delivery.php etc. and i’ve added the code in my config/main.php and i don’t get why only the app.php translations are working. Any string on all other files are not showing… Do you have any idea why ? Or is it possible to work only with app.php ?

Kind regards

my configuration code

```
'i18n' => [
       'translations' => [
           '*'=> [
               'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
               'basePath' => '$app/messages',
               'sourceLanguage' => 'en-US',
               'fileMap' => [
                   'app' => 'app.php',
                   'app/maker' => 'maker.php',
                   'app/producer' => 'producer.php',
                   'app/product' => 'product.php',
                   'app/delivery' => 'delivery.php',
                   'app/explication'=>'explication.php',
                   'app/faq'=>'faq.php',
                   'app/greensocial'=>'greensocial.php',
                   'app/rbac-admin'=>'rbac-admin.php',
                   'app/yii'=>'yii.php',
                   'app/error' => 'error.php',

               ],
           ],
       ],
   ],
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing: `'$app/messages'` for [basePath](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-i18n-phpmessagesource#$basePath-detail) cannot work, as an [alias](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-aliases) is required to start with `@`.

The appropriate value should be `@backend/messages` if your using yii2-app-advanced ([@backend](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-path-aliases) gets defined by default) or `@app/backend/messages` otherwise, I guess.